# What's "pseudo time" when used in comparison with semaphores

Tags: terminology, concurrency

I'm currently listening to Alan Kays' talk "Is it really complex or did we just make it complicated ?" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubaX1Smg6pY&= ) where he says that "semaphores were a bad idea and there was something called pseudo time that was superior" (at 51:40 on the linked video).
Maybe I misunderstood the word "pseudo time", but do you know anything about those ?

Answer (score 8):

I believe he may be referring to this paper: [NAMING AND SYNCHRONIZATION IN A DECENTRALIZED COMPUTER SYSTEM](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-205.pdf).

Comment: Link is broken.  This works for now:  https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/16279